# How do you Select an existing vector Layer and Edit it, using python?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I'm developing a small plugin that needs to be able to select a vector layer programatically based on what layer the user has selected. However I'm not sure how to do so.

I believe I found the two elements I need to make it work: setCurrentLayer and selectedLayer from the QgisLegendInterface, but I'm not certain how they work or how they are implemented, I cannot either find any examples of them other than in the API.

Am I close? Or is there a better/proper form of doing this?

Comment: try to read http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/ ..most probably you would be able to answer yourself then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the qgis.util.iface object which will give you access to all layers including the current selected layer:

myLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()